# Extract words that only have repeating set of character(s) 2-4 times

Tags: bash, unix, grep

Sample input:

```
123123123 aaaaa  abababab  aaab baaa abcde1abcde1
aaaaaa 1212121212
```

Expected output:

```
123123123
abababab
abcde1abcde1
aaaaaa
```

here's what I tried:

```
egrep '(.)\1\1{2,4}' test
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `grep` version supports `-o` and `-w` options

> -o, --only-matching
>             Print  only  the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output
>             line.
>
> -w, --word-regexp
>             Select only those lines containing matches that form whole  words.   The  test  is  that  the  matching
>             substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character.
>             Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a  non-word  constituent  character.
>             Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.

`egrep` is deprecated as far as I know and `grep -E` is equivalent

Adding `-o` option to OP's attempt, as well as `-w` to avoid matching portion of word

```
$ grep -owE '(.)\1\1{2,4}' ip.txt
aaaaa
aaaaaa
```

Changing the regex

```
$ grep -owE '(.{1,})\1{1,3}' ip.txt
123123123
abababab
abcde1abcde1
aaaaaa
```

- `.{1,}` one or more characters to be repeated
- `\1{1,3}` maximum 4 times, so we need to match again at least one more time and max 3 more times